# How much resistance will I need to drop the voltage?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-divider, ohms-law

9 Volts is applied to circuit. There is a LED which runs on 3 Volts. I want to drop 6 Volts. how much resistance (\$R_1\$) would I need for that?

[image: Circuit image]

Comment: That all depends on how much current the LED requires (or how much you want to give it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is: Any resistor will drop 6V.

The LED has a *fixed* drop of 3V.  All the rest of the voltage has to be dropped across the resistor, regardless of its resistance*.

The purpose of that resistor is *not* to drop the voltage, but to *limit the current*.

You need to specify an amount of current the LED needs, and then use simple Ohm's law to calculate the resistor to limit the current to that amount:

$$
R=\frac{V}{I} = \frac{9-3}{I}
$$

When you know what *I* should be you can find the resistor.

---

<sub>*assuming enough current flows to allow the LED to conduct</sub>